# BizTalk SSO Configuration - There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper

Tags: biztalk, single-sign-on

I have a two node BTS2010 group with a separate SQL Server hosting the BTS databases including SSODB; Biz01, Biz02 and Sql01. This environment was configured by a previous employee and I have no documentation available.

There seems to be something not right with the SSO config but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

When I run ssoconfig -status on Biz02 all looks good - it tells me that the SSO Server is Biz02 and the SQL Server is Sql01 plus a load of other stuff. However, when I run the same command on Biz01 I get the message: "Error 0xC0002A0F: Could not contact the SSO server 'Sql01'. Check that SSO is configured and that the SSO service is running on that server'

I'm not clear on what Biz01 is trying to do here - is it trying to reach the EntSSO windows service on Biz02 via an RPC call, before ultimately attempting to retrie config info from Sql01?

I have checked that the ENTSSO service is running on Biz01, Biz02 and that the RPC service is running on each of the three servers.

Can anyone help advise what further steps I can take to determine the root cause of this configuration problem?

Many thanks

Rob.

Comment: How did you eventually address this problem? Can you please share the steps that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have your servers clustered or not but I've run into something similar before within a cluster.  Your SSO name should be your network name and not the individual computers name.   Here's an [post](http://kentweare.blogspot.com/2009/08/biztalk-2009-clustering-sso-issue.html) about the issue I had.  Hope it helps.